# Selective flattening of a Python list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, flatten

Suppose I have a list containing (among other things) sublists of different types:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4], {5, 6}]
```

that I'd like to flatten in a selective way, depending on the type of its elements (i.e. I'd like to only flatten `sets`, and leave the rest unflattened):

```
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6]
```

My current solution is a function, but just for my intellectual curiosity, I wonder if it's possible to do it with a single list comprehension?

Comment: Flattening out the set seems a little funny for a lot of applications since the ordering will be arbitrary (and lists are ordered).

Comment: I totally agree about that, and I gave the issue some thought, but it turns that in my application, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List comprehensions aren't designed for flattening (since they don't have a way to combine the values corresponding to multiple input items).

While you *can* get around this with nested list comprehensions, this requires each element in your top level list to be iterable.

Honestly, just use a function for this. It's the cleanest way.

Comment: I don't undersdand what you mean by "LC is not designed for flattening": what about the `[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]` pattern?

Comment: @cjauvin: The problem here is that the second `for item in sublist` part requires that the sublists actually be iterable, which isn't the case for the `1` and `2` elements in your collection. To get around this, you have to create single-element iterables out of your scalar elements—which is doable, as senderie shows, but it's questionable whether it's something you _should_ do.

Comment: @cjauvin It's not designed for general-purpose flattening (e.g. flattening things with arbitrary nesting levels). It can be used to transform a *consistently* N-dimensional set of nested lists into a flat list, but it can't handle a varying-dimensional set of nested lists.

Answer (score 4):

Amber is probably right that a function is preferable for something like this. On the other hand, there's always room for a little variation. I'm assuming the nesting is never more than one level deep -- if it is ever more than one level deep, then you should *definitely* prefer a function for this. But if not, this is a potentially viable approach.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Set
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(x if isinstance(x, Set) else (x,) for x in l))
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6]
```

The non-itertools way to do this would involve nested list comprehensions. Better to break that into two lines:

```
>>> packaged = (x if isinstance(x, collections.Set) else (x,) for x in l)
>>> [x for y in packaged for x in y]
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6]
```

I don't have a strong intuition about whether either of these would be faster or slower than a straightforward function. These create lots of singleton tuples -- that's kind of a waste -- but they also happen at LC speed, which is usually pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice solution. Now I have the troublesome issue of deciding which answer to accept.. Amber's opinion that it should be a function (to which I fully agree), or yours, that demonstrates that it's a least *possible*, which was my initial question..

Comment: Well, this one doesn't actually show how do it in a single comprehension; it shows how to do it in an itertools.chain plus a generator expression or a comprehension plus a generator expression… But I think it _does_ show enough that turning it into a nested comprehension is a pretty easy exercise for the reader, so I gave it a +1.

Comment: Well, I certainly won't be offended if you accept Amber's. It's probably the better answer all things considered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatten](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#flatten) function from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library:

```
from funcy import flatten, isa

flat_list = flatten(your_list, follow=isa(set))
```

You can also peek at [its implementation](https://github.com/Suor/funcy/blob/1.0.0/funcy/seqs.py#L147).

Comment: +1 for the reference to funcy, which seems quite nice